# How to inject into classes that are deserialized

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a configuration file where one property is a collection (List) that also is serialized/deserialized together with other objects in the class.

The configuration file is registered like this:

```
Container.RegisterType<Infrastructure.IConfigurationService<Providers.Configuration>, Infrastructure.ConfigurationServiceBase<Providers.Configuration>>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionProperty("Filename", "Providers.Configuration.xml"));
```

The ConfigurationServiceBase class has a property called Configuration, which deserializes upon first access of the property.

So, the deserialization occurs outside of the prism "scope", and so any properties I decorate with the [Dependency] attribute is ignored.

How can I have prism/unity inject these properties?

EDIT: To elaborate my intentions, I have created a Module located in its own assembly. The configuration file contains a list of "providers" which i work on in my application. These providers all derive from a common parent class, but have different implementations. These implementations need to access a data "service" i've created and initialized in another module/assembly. But since these providers are created when deserializing they are not injected.

Comment: Smells of "poor separation of concern". Why does a DTO need to have services injected into it? Consider refactoring out the code that actually consumes the services and the configuration object.

Comment: Are the properties on the Configuration object?

Comment: Yes, it's a List<> that gets deserialized.